# get past 5 min data in elb log file bash

Tags: bash, logging

I am working on a script to fetch the last five minutes of this log when user prompts **10:07:30**. How can I do this bash? Give is the part of my script.

`2017-07-19T10:00:37.306805Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:58814 10.0.2.203:80 0.000042 0.000579 0.00002 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:01:56.572506Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:58870 10.0.2.203:80 0.000038 0.000603 0.000019 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:02:15.628179Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:58904 10.0.2.203:80 0.000044 0.000583 0.00002 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:03:34.875186Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:58958 10.0.2.203:80 0.00004 0.000597 0.00002 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:04:27.468370Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59400 10.0.2.203:80 0.000065 0.000513 0.000019 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:05:46.601192Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59446 10.0.2.203:80 0.000057 0.000544 0.000021 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:06:05.782121Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59492 10.0.2.203:80 0.000044 0.000667 0.00002 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:07:24.983365Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59546 10.0.2.203:80 0.000041 0.000434 0.000019 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:08:00.975682Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59794 10.0.2.203:80 0.000037 0.000521 0.000019 200 200 0 809 
2017-07-19T10:09:20.152264Z elb-sam30-ftpoc-prod 35.163.110.235:59842 10.0.2.203:80 0.000045 0.000571 0.00002 200 200 0 809`

Comment: If the log file is written through rsyslogd and your system is running systemd, you can use journalctl with the --since flag.

Comment: This is an external log file

Comment: So you want to show anything 5 minutes or less from the 10:07:30 (or whatever a user enters)? What about the date?

Comment: Yes, we also need to consider date if user prompted a value similar to 00:01:10

Comment: So the user adds a time AND a date? If they enter a date, in what format is it entered?

Comment: Let's assume the date he entered will be Thu Aug 17 10:07:11 IST 2017 and I need to get 5 min earlier data.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat="Thu Aug 17 10:07:11 IST 2017"
dat1=$(sed -rn 's/([[:alpha:]]{3}[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]{3}[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]{2}[[:blank:]])(.*)(IST )(.*$)/\1\4 \2/p' <<< $dat)
edat=$(date -d "$dat1" +%s)
awk -v rdat=$edat '{ram1=substr($1,1,4)" "substr($1,6,2)" "substr($1,9,2)" "substr($1,12,2)" "substr($1,15,2)" "substr($1,18,2);ram1=mktime(ram1);ram=rdat-(60*5); if (ram1 >= ram) { print $0 } }' logfile
```

awk broken down:

```
{       ram1=mktime(substr($1,1,4)" "substr($1,6,2)" "substr($1,9,2)" "substr($1,12,2)" "substr($1,15,2)" "substr($1,18,2))
        ram=rdat-(60*5)
        if (ram1 >= ram) {
                print $0
        }
}
```

We would first parse the date with sed to attain the date in a format we can then pass to the command date to allow us to attain the date format (seconds since epoch). This variable edat is then passed to awk as the variable rdat. This date has five minutes subtracted (60*5) and is then compared to the dates in the log file after they too are converted to epoch with the mktime function.

Comment: Thank You Ram for your script. I didn't understand the substring part and the values in it. Could you please provide some reference on it.

Comment: substr($1,1,4) means take the first space delimited field i.e. "2017-07-19T10:00:37.306805Z" and then extract from the first field, 4 characters. The result would be 2017. The next substr command is getting the month and then the day....so on and so forth.

Comment: I tried executing the script, but could'nt get any output . Could you please tell the steps to use and debug the script if possible.

Comment: The script will work if all the data is consistent with your test data and the time date is entered in exactly the same format also.